# Getting uninitialized constant error when trying to run tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I just updated all my gems and I'm finding that I'm getting errors when trying to run Test::Unit tests. I'm getting the error copied below. That comes from creating new, empty Rails project, scaffolding a simple model, and running `rake test`.

Tried Googling "uninitialized constant" and TestResultFailureSupport. The only thing I found was [this bug report](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=21856&aid=22318&group_id=5650) from 2007.

I'm using OS X.

These are the gems that I updated right before the tests stopped working:

```
$ sudo gem outdated
Password:
RedCloth (4.2.1 < 4.2.2)
RubyInline (3.8.1 < 3.8.2)
ZenTest (4.1.1 < 4.1.3)
bluecloth (2.0.4 < 2.0.5)
capistrano (2.5.5 < 2.5.8)
haml (2.0.9 < 2.2.1)
hoe (2.2.0 < 2.3.2)
json (1.1.6 < 1.1.7)
mocha (0.9.5 < 0.9.7)
rest-client (1.0.2 < 1.0.3)
thoughtbot-factory_girl (1.2.1 < 1.2.2)
thoughtbot-shoulda (2.10.1 < 2.10.2)
```

Has anyone else seen this issue? Any troubleshooting suggestions?

---

### UPDATE

On a hunch I downgraded ZenTest from 4.1.3 back to 4.1.1 and now everything works again.

Still curious to know if anyone else has seen this or has any interesting comments or insights.

---

```
$ rake test
(in /Users/me/foo)
/usr/local/bin/ruby -I"lib:test" "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/unit/helpers/users_helper_test.rb" "test/unit/user_test.rb" 
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:105:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Test::Unit::TestResult::TestResultFailureSupport (NameError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/test-unit-2.0.2/lib/test/unit/testresult.rb:28
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/test-unit-2.0.2/lib/test/unit/ui/testrunnermediator.rb:9
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
     ... 6 levels...
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/autorunner.rb:214:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/autorunner.rb:12:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit.rb:278
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5
/usr/local/bin/ruby -I"lib:test" "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/functional/users_controller_test.rb"
```

Comment: FYI, for anyone trying this on Windows, I had the exact same issue. I uninstalled test-unit ('gem uninstall test-unit') and  all it's dependencies, and that did it.

Comment: I had this issue on a Linux machine and uninstalling test-unit gem worked for me too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can happen if modules are declared in a single statement when the parent module they are nested inside has not yet been loaded. I haven't looked at the code in those gems, but my hunch is that's what is happening. Chuck's solution would suggest that. calling `gem 'test-unit'` first will load the parent module, so the setup of zen test ends up working ok.

e.g.

```
module Foo::Bar
  def do_stuff
    # insert awesomeness here...
  end
end
```

Will result in an error if the parent Foo module hasn't already been defined (e.g. by another gem)

A safer way to declare this is

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    def do_stuff
      # insert awesomeness here...
    end
  end
end
```

May be a bug in Zentest that needs patching.

Comment: This works... as long as you are not overriding existing functionality with your "patch".  In that case, when the module is loaded from the "base" library, it will overwrite your patch.  I like using `module Foo::Bar` to ensure that the "base" has been loaded prior to my patch.  That is also why I prefer `Foo.class_eval` over reopening with `class Foo`.

Answer (score 5):

This apparently comes from using Test::Unit 2.0 with the old Test::Unit. According to Kouhei Sutou on RubyForge, it [can be fixed](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=21856&aid=22318&group_id=5650) by calling `gem 'test-unit'` before you `require 'test/unit'`.

Comment: or uninstall the test-unit gem (if that's an available option).

Answer (score 3):

As this link suggests http://floehopper.lighthouseapp.com/projects/22289-mocha/tickets/50 
it may happen due to preliminary initialization of mocha lib.
To prevent it from happeing it is advisable to add line

```
config.gem 'test-unit', :lib => 'test/unit'
```

to config/environment.rb

Comment: in cases where this works, note you can also just put in config/environments/test.rb

Answer (score 3):

Here is the recipe for test_unit 2.0.7 on Rails 2.3.5:

In config/environments/test.rb:

```
config.gem 'test-unit', :version => '2.0.7', :lib => false
```

In test_helper.rb, 
              add `require 'test/unit'`, 
immediately after `require 'test_help'`

So it looks like this:

```
require 'test_help'
require 'test/unit'
```

If you receive this error: 
`%': one hash required (ArgumentError)`,
 upgrade gem `i18n` to v0.3.6.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this without mocha or shoulda installed.

[This post suggests it's due to an incompatibility in test-unit >= 2.0](http://lindsaar.net/2009/10/29/rails-unit-tests-uninitialized-constant-test-unit-testresult-testresultfailuresupport), which I installed as a dependency for the systools gems. Downgrading to 1.2.3 worked for me, a simple require might also.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with me too.
Nothing above mentioned worked for me except downgrading test-unit back to 1.2.3
I'm missing the coloring of the test-unit 2.x

Comment: You can add the `redgreen` gem to get your coloring back.

Answer (score 1):

Found the (ugly) solution:

`gem 'unit/test'`
must be called inside the tests too, not only in the `Rakefile`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today on Mac OS X 10.6. My solution is as follows:

```
config.gem 'test-unit', :lib => 'test/unit', :version => '1.2.3'
config.gem 'autotest'
config.gem 'cucumber'
config.gem 'cucumber-rails', :lib => false
config.gem 'ffaker', :lib => 'faker'
config.gem 'rspec', :lib => false, :version => '>= 1.2.0'
config.gem 'rspec-rails', :lib => false, :version => '>= 1.2.0'
config.gem 'selenium-client', :lib => 'selenium'
config.gem "thoughtbot-factory_girl", :lib => 'factory_girl', :source => "http://gems.github.com"
config.gem 'thoughtbot-shoulda', :lib => 'shoulda'
config.gem 'webrat'
config.gem 'ZenTest', :lib => 'zentest'
```

Answer (score 1):

As with aronchick's comment, for me (OS X 10.6) solution was

```
sudo gem uninstall test-unit
```

all versions.

Answer (score 1):

You get auto_test to work again with something like

```
RUBY="ruby  -I.:lib:test -rubygems -e 'gem \"test-unit\"'" autotest
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a nuby to rails but I am still learning and hopefully always will be :-).

Rails 2.3 production environment using Ruby Enterprise Edition and passenger can produce a totally misleading useless error during startup (/var/log/passenger.log). Something like:

Exception NameError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (uninitialized constant XXX)

If you run script/console on the production server, you may see:

```
Loading production environment (Rails 2.3.4)
/home/ubuntu/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:105:in  const_missing:NameError: uninitialized constant XXX
```

This is happening to me in this instance only in production environment, not staging, not development. After a full day of research and experiments, I have concluded that in the production environment, REE or something must pre-load classes and the pre-loader apparently does not like to see classes being re-opened before they are created (an educated guess).

In app/models/calendar.rb:

```
  Class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
    # This defines the class
  End
```

In app/models/event.rb

```
  Class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    # This desined the class
  End
  Class Calendar
    # This is supposed to 're-open' the Calendar class
    has_many :events
  end
```

The above generic sample code snippet can cause startup issue. I am not sure of the order that pre-loading classes takes place but I suspect that may be the issue. I moved the ‘has_many :events’ into the class definition in app/modeles/calendar.rb and my app now starts without error.

So, a good rule to follow is to put your Active Record Associations (has_many, belongs_to) inside the defining class (where the class is created).

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following line to your environment.rb, or your config/environments/test.rb this should fix the issue

```
config.gem "test-unit", :lib => "test/unit", :version => ">=2.0.9", :env => "test"
```

I Believe you will need to add it before the mocha line if you use mocha.