# Setting up teamcity to run rails specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, teamcity

I'm trying to set up teamcity 5.0.2 to run my rails projects specs (just rake spec)

My setup is:

- local git repo
- rails app root in
  side it (git_root/site_root)

my rake runner settings are:

- path to rakefile: site_root/Rakefile
- working directory: site_root
- rake tasks: spec
- attached reporters: rspec

everything else is default.

when I run the build i get the following output:

```
Checking for changes
Clearing temporary directory: /home/michaelbaldry/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp
Checkout directory: /home/michaelbaldry/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/65c3a24ba4d13a41
Updating sources: server side checkout...
[Updating sources: server side checkout...] Building incremental patch for VCS root: local projects
[Updating sources: server side checkout...] Repository sources transferred
Starting build process in /home/michaelbaldry/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/65c3a24ba4d13a41/site_root
/usr/bin/ruby /home/michaelbaldry/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/plugins/rake-runner/lib/rb/runner/rakerunner.rb --rakefile /home/michaelbaldry/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/65c3a24ba4d13a41/site_root/Rakefile spec SPEC_OPTS=--require 'teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter' --format Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter:matrix
(in /home/michaelbaldry/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/65c3a24ba4d13a41/site_root)
LoadError: no such file to load -- /home/michaelbaldry/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/65c3a24ba4d13a41/site_root/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer Stacktrace: /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require' /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require' /home/michaelbaldry/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/65c3a24ba4d13a41/site_root/config/boot.rb:45:in `load_initializer' /home/michaelbaldry/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/65c3a24ba4d13a41/site_root/config/boot.rb:38:in `run' /home/michaelbaldry/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/65c3a24ba4d13a41/site_root/config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!' /home/michaelbaldry/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/65c3a24ba4d13a41/site_root/config/boot.rb:109 /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require' /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require' /home/michaelbaldry/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/65c3a24ba4d13a41/site_root/Rakefile:4 /home/michaelbaldry/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load' /home/michaelbaldry/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile' /home/michaelbaldry/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile' /home/michaelbaldry/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/plugins/rake-runner/lib/rb/runner/rake_ext.rb:621:in `standard_exception_handling' /home/michaelbaldry/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile' /home/michaelbaldry/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `run' /home/michaelbaldry/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/plugins/rake-runner/lib/rb/runner/rake_ext.rb:621:in `standard_exception_handling' /home/michaelbaldry/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run' /home/michaelbaldry/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/plugins/rake-runner/lib/rb/runner/rake_ext.rb:357:in `run' /home/michaelbaldry/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/plugins/rake-runner/lib/rb/runner/rakerunner.rb:79 Source: /home/michaelbaldry/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/65c3a24ba4d13a41/site_root/Rakefile:4
Rake aborted!
Process exit code: 1
Build finished
```

any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  I clicked on the "Build Log" tab and was able to see more detail than the "Overview" tab.

I found a [workaround](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5273011#5273011):

```
gem uninstall test-unit
```

I can't say I like this solution but at least it worked.  The Build Log lead me to google for uninitialized constant Test::Unit::TestResult::TestResultFailureSupport which lead me to another ["uninitialized constant error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145318/getting-uninitialized-constant-error-when-trying-to-run-tests) resource on stackoverflow.com which had the solution.